# How to load scripts in mvc 4 while using ajax call the partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Home page**

```
 <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="onBegin(&quot;/Organisation/SearchForStudent/&quot;)" data-ajax-complete="onComplete" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#dvmain" href="/Organisation/SearchForStudent/"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span class="nav-label">Search for Student</span></a>


    <div id="dvmain"></div>
```

**partial view**

```
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading" id="MainHeaddivStaff">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>Search for Staff</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../js/plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var staffid = 0;
    var BrnachIDforleave = 0;
    var foot = 0;
</script>
```

in home page only html tags of partial view are bind, but script are not bind.

Comment: Partial view is not load in view page source...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all the script tags shall be included in the landing page (Home page in your case, if it is the landing page).

Try loading the script in the home page.

Answer (score 0):

put them in partial page as

```
     @section scripts {
    <script src="../js/plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var staffid = 0;
    var BrnachIDforleave = 0;
    var foot = 0;
</script>

    }
```

Comment: it throws an error like below "The file "~/Views/Login/Master_Admin.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method."

Comment: i would say start over and create a new partial view in that view just paste the old views code + make sure to add @layout = null at the top of the partial view https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOXX1.png

Comment: Just add @Layout = null to top of your partial view and see if it works